# Javascript - Double values without floating points?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Which type of variable should I use in order to calculate double values without floating points?

i.e. let `x = 0.6`;

I want `x*3/4` to be calculated as `0.45` instead of `0.44999999999999996`.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

There is only one type of number in Javascript... [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) :)

You might try something like `.toFixed()`

`(0.6 * 3/4).toFixed(2)` => `0.45`